# Firebase user isnt logged in after logging in and refreshing page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a simple form for login...

```
<div id="alertLogIn" class="alert alert-danger" style="margin: 20px 0px;"></div>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginEmail" name="loginEmail" placeholder="e-mail">
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" placeholder="password">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="submit" id="doLogin" value="LOGIN" class="loginButton2" style="font-size:18px">
    </div>
</form>
```

My JS is like so

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        email: $('#loginEmail').val(),
        password: $('#loginPassword').val()
    };

    if (data.email === '') {
        console.log("email is empty");
        $('#alertLogIn').show();
        $('#alertLogIn').text("email is empty");
    } else if (data.password === '') {
        console.log("password is empty");
        $('#alertLogIn').show();
        $('#alertLogIn').text("password is empty");
    } else {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
            .then(function (authData) {
                auth = authData;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
                $('#alertLogIn').show();

                $('#alertLogIn').text(error.message);
            });
    }

});
```

and I also have an observer

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    console.log(user);
    if (user) {
        auth = user;
        getUserName.username = user.uid;
        console.log(getUserName.username);
    } else {
        getUserName.username = null;
        auth = null;
    }
});


var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
//create firebase references
var Auth = firebase.auth();
```

When I login, the console will print out the user ID as intended, however, if I refresh the page, its saying null. What is causing this?

Comment: Could you re-read your last sentence and make sure it says what you mean for it to say?  Also are you adding that observer immediately when the page loads?  If not, it won't pick up any changes to the auth state.  Please edit the question to be more complete about what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Are you running the code in an unusual environment? If not, can you try to reproduce it in a site like stackblitz.com - so tht we can all take a look there?